# Outlook REST API Webhooks Subscription Retry if Application has Crashed

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I would like to use the Outlook REST API webhooks / subscriptions to update calendar events in my application. I couldn't find any information in the documentation regarding whether the Outlook API will retry sending Notifications if my application is down / crashed or sends a 500 error. I know the Google API uses exponential backoff to retry sending. Does Outlook do something similar?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. From the Microsoft Graph [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscription_post_subscriptions):

> When the subscribed resource changes, the webhooks facility sends a notification to your notification URL with the following payload. The notification endpoint must send a response of `200` or `204` with no response body within 30 seconds otherwise the notification attempt will be retried at exponentially increasing intervals. Services that consistently take 30 seconds or more may be throttled and receive a sparser notification set.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That's great to hear. Do you know if this is limited to the Microsoft Graph API? Or if the Outlook REST API does the same and it just isn't included in their documentation? @mark-lafleur

Comment: They're actually the same (or rather Graph consumers the Outlook API). As an aside, I strongly recommend using Graph instead of the Outlook REST API. Going forward, Microsoft Graph will be the primary endpoint for just about everything (Outlook, SharePoint, OneDrive, AAD, etc.).

Comment: Broken link....

Comment: I think this info is now out of date - looks like it might be 3 seconds now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#processing-the-change-notification